# Shiny - Control Widgets Inside Leaflet Map

Tags: html, r, leaflet, shiny

I have a simple shiny-app with just a dropdown listing districts of Afghanistan and a leaflet map of the same. 
[image]

The shape file can be accessed at this [link](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/AFG_adm_shp.zip) - using AFG_adm2.shp from http://www.gadm.org/download

here's the app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

afg <- readOGR(dsn = "data", layer ="AFG_adm2", verbose = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test App"),
    selectInput("yours", choices = c("",afg$NAME_2), label = "Select Country:"),
    actionButton("zoomer","reset zoom"),
    leafletOutput("mymap")

)

server <- function(input, output){
  initial_lat = 33.93
  initial_lng = 67.71
  initial_zoom = 5

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(afg) %>% #addTiles() %>%
       addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, color = "#00000", weight = 1) 
  })

  proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap")

  observe({
    if(input$yours!=""){
      #get the selected polygon and extract the label point 
      selected_polygon <- subset(afg,afg$NAME_2==input$yours)
      polygon_labelPt <- selected_polygon@polygons[[1]]@labpt

      #remove any previously highlighted polygon
      proxy %>% removeShape("highlighted_polygon")

      #center the view on the polygon 
      proxy %>% setView(lng=polygon_labelPt[1],lat=polygon_labelPt[2],zoom=7)

      #add a slightly thicker red polygon on top of the selected one
      proxy %>% addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, weight = 2,color="red",data=selected_polygon,layerId="highlighted_polygon")
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$zoomer, {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% setView(lat = initial_lat, lng = initial_lng, zoom = initial_zoom) %>% removeShape("highlighted_polygon") 
  })


}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT: I'm actually trying to add an action button which resets zoom to a default value (using leafletproxy and setview) and I want to put this button on the top-right corner of the map instead of it being above the map.**

Can I use `addLayersControl` to do this?

**EDIT2:**

Code in full-app:

```
# Create the map
    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(afg) %>% addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(fill = TRUE,
                    fillColor = ~factpal(acdf$WP_2012), #which color for which attribute
                    stroke = TRUE, 
                    fillOpacity = 1, #how dark/saturation the fill color should be
                    color = "black", #color of attribute boundaries
                    weight = 1, #weight of attribute boundaies
                    smoothFactor = 1,
                    layerId = aid
                    #popup = ac_popup
        ) %>% addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, color = "#000000", weight = 1) %>%
        addLegend("bottomleft", pal = factpal, values = ~WP_2012,
                  title = "Party",
                  opacity = 1
        ) %>% setView(lng = initial_lng, lat = initial_lat, zoom = initial_zoom) %>%
        addControl(html = actionButton("zoomer1","Reset", icon = icon("arrows-alt")), position = "topright")
    })
```

I can't see the map tiles from `addTiles` or the zoom reset button from `addControl`. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `addControl` function directly:

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(afg) %>% #addTiles() %>%
        addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, color = "#00000", weight = 1) %>%
        addControl(actionButton("zoomer","Reset"),position="topright")
})
```

Comment: or `%>% mapview::addHomeButton(ext = raster::extent(afg), layer.name = "afg", position = "topright")`

Comment: This lets me see the Reset button for a second after which it disappears (or goes behind the map layer?) in my full app.

Comment: @TimSalabim mapview works fine, but how can I style and edit the button? Also, I was using an observer with actiobutton which was zooming out AND deselecting a selected polygon.

Comment: @ProgSnob sorry but you can't style the button beyond the `layer.name` argument.

Comment: you can try setting the layerId etc but it's hard to figure out what's happening if it works in the minimal example  but not in your full app if you don't post the code.

Comment: @NicE any idea why the controls disappears once the map is fully rendered?

Comment: @NicE check Edit2 in the post above. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, when I run your code removing the layerId in the addPolygons and the factpal part (I removed them just because you didn't provide that code) it runs fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the shiny absolutePanel() function in your UI, E.g.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

afg <- readOGR(dsn = "data", layer ="AFG_adm2", verbose = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
tags$head(
    tags$style(
        HTML(
            '
            .outer {
                position: fixed;
                top: 80px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #controls-filters {
                background-color: white;
                border:none;
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                z-index:150;
            }
            '
        )
    )
), 
titlePanel("Test App"),
absolutePanel(
    id = "controls-filters",
    class = "panel panel-default",
    fixed = TRUE,
    draggable = TRUE,
    top = 100,
    left = "auto",
    right = 20,
    bottom = "auto",
    width = 330,
    height = "auto",
    selectInput("yours", choices = c("", afg$NAME_2), label = "Select Country:"),
    actionButton("zoomer", "reset zoom")
),
div(class = "outer", leafletOutput("mymap"))
        )

server <- function(input, output){
initial_lat = 33.93
initial_lng = 67.71
initial_zoom = 5

output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(afg) %>% #addTiles() %>%
        addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, color = "#00000", weight = 1) 
})

proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap")

observe({
    if(input$yours!=""){
        #get the selected polygon and extract the label point 
        selected_polygon <- subset(afg,afg$NAME_2==input$yours)
        polygon_labelPt <- selected_polygon@polygons[[1]]@labpt

        #remove any previously highlighted polygon
        proxy %>% removeShape("highlighted_polygon")

        #center the view on the polygon 
        proxy %>% setView(lng=polygon_labelPt[1],lat=polygon_labelPt[2],zoom=7)

        #add a slightly thicker red polygon on top of the selected one
        proxy %>% addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, weight = 2,color="red",data=selected_polygon,layerId="highlighted_polygon")
    }
})

observeEvent(input$zoomer, {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% setView(lat = initial_lat, lng = initial_lng, zoom = initial_zoom) %>% removeShape("highlighted_polygon") 
})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This should get you started but I would recommend structuring your app in such a way that it has a stand alone CSS file.

Comment: No this doesn't work for me. I already have an absolutePanel in my full-app and if I add another and position it relative to map, it is not visible anymore. Did it go behind the map layer?

Comment: Really getting into CSS territory now. I'll edit my answer and provide more detail.